# VPN connection terminates: L2TP failed to set port-mapping for en0, errorCode: -65564

Tags: macbook-pro, network, vpn, monterey

The following issue surfaced last week and I am not sure anymore if this happened *before* or *after* I upgraded to Monterey.

I am using a VPN connection for work but since last week this connection only lasts for 60 to 90 seconds. In the first 60 seconds everything *is working*. The machine is connected and has internet. After these 60 seconds the internet connection stops working and around 30 seconds later the VPN client tells me that the VPN connection has been terminated.

Now, after some trying around it was suggested to me to try to access the internet from another connection so I switched from my home router to a mobile hot spot.

And there you go. With the mobile hot spot everything is working fine for hours.

Clearly, this makes the router the main suspect but I have been working with it for months now and since I didn't touch it, I find it hard to believe that it is the cause.

I've searched the internet for this issue but I couldn't find anything useful. Is there anything I can do? At least to get more information about *where* this issue truly originates from?

## Logging output

I took a look at the `/var/log/ppp.log` file and compared both cases. The main difference, and what catches the eye, are those lines here:

```
Thu Jan 20 09:47:09 2022 : L2TP failed to set port-mapping for en0, errorCode: -65564
Thu Jan 20 09:47:09 2022 : L2TP port-mapping for en0 became invalid. is Connected: 1, Protocol: None, Private Port: 0, Previous publicAddress: (0), Previous publicPort: (0)
Thu Jan 20 09:47:09 2022 : L2TP clearing port-mapping for en0
```

Below you can look at both entire sessions.

### Working (mobile hot spot)

```
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : l2tp_get_router_address
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.43.1 from dict 1
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : L2TP connecting to server '85.237.31.244' (85.237.31.244)...
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : IPSec connection started
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : IPSec phase 1 client started
Thu Jan 20 14:51:30 2022 : IPSec phase 1 server replied
Thu Jan 20 14:51:31 2022 : IPSec phase 2 started
Thu Jan 20 14:51:31 2022 : IPSec phase 2 established
Thu Jan 20 14:51:31 2022 : IPSec connection established
Thu Jan 20 14:51:31 2022 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP received SCCRP
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP sent SCCCN
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP sent ICRQ
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP received ICRP
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP sent ICCN
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP connection established.
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : L2TP set port-mapping for en0, interface: 6, protocol: 0, privatePort: 0
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : using link 0
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : Using interface ppp0
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:18]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x57c42b33> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth eap> <magic 0x5e3d2499>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFNAK.
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x5e3d2499>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFACK.
Thu Jan 20 14:51:32 2022 : sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x5e3d2499>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x57c42b33> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x57c42b33> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x57c42b33]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0xc2 <b59776d4e95ffd9c447b70655c5808b6>, name = "xl2tpd"]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : sent [CHAP Response id=0xc2 <6399983a35e92f14499ef668e18b2898000000000000000047db3fdec44452683582e60fd1d8ef17cb0308c7c24d6bff00>, name = "sfalk"]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x5e3d2499]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : rcvd [CHAP Success id=0xc2 "S=E25C4E6D7589D22C958A063AE5018D4349014605"]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::f218:98ff:fe5f:11f2>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 10.255.255.0>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : ipcp: returning Configure-ACK
Thu Jan 20 14:51:35 2022 : sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 10.255.255.0>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 10.10.20.8> <ms-dns1 10.10.10.1> <ms-dns3 10.10.10.1>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 10.10.20.8> <ms-dns1 10.10.10.1> <ms-dns3 10.10.10.1>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 57 01 01 00 0e 01 0a f2 18 98 ff fe 5f 11 f2]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2 <addr 10.10.20.8> <ms-dns1 10.10.10.1> <ms-dns3 10.10.10.1>]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : ipcp: up
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : local  IP address 10.10.20.8
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : remote IP address 10.255.255.0
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : primary   DNS address 10.10.10.1
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : secondary DNS address 10.10.10.1
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : Received protocol dictionaries
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : l2tp_wait_input: Address added. previous interface setting (name: en0, address: 192.168.43.145), current interface setting (name: ppp0, family: PPP, address: 10.10.20.8, subnet: 255.0.0.0, destination: 10.255.255.0).
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : Committed PPP store on install command
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : rcvd [IPV6 data]
   60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   '`....$..........'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00   '................'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16   3a 00 05 02 00 00 01 00   '........:.......'
   8f 00 6e 8a 00 00 00 01   04 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00   '..n.............'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 02               '............'
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : Unsupported protocol 0x57 received
Thu Jan 20 14:51:36 2022 : sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x2 00 57 60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00 00 00 ...]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:37 2022 : rcvd [IPV6 data]
   60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   '`....$..........'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00   '................'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16   3a 00 05 02 00 00 01 00   '........:.......'
   8f 00 6e 8a 00 00 00 01   04 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00   '..n.............'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 02               '............'
Thu Jan 20 14:51:37 2022 : Unsupported protocol 0x57 received
Thu Jan 20 14:51:37 2022 : sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 00 57 60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00 00 00 ...]
Thu Jan 20 14:51:39 2022 : L2TP port-mapping update for en0 ignored: VPN is the Primary interface. Public Address: 0, Protocol: None, Private Port: 0, Public Port: 0
Thu Jan 20 14:51:39 2022 : L2TP clearing port-mapping for en0
```

### Not working (router)

#### Router event log

Establishing the VPN connection, I can see these log entries in my router's event log:

```
24.01.22  10:19:24  Wireless LAN transmission quality increased by reduced channel bandwidth (2,4 GHz). [3 messages since 24.01.22 10:19:04]
24.01.22  10:19:01  Forwarding to 192.168.178.69 (sfalk) added for port 1701.
24.01.22  10:19:01  Forwarding to 192.168.178.69 (sfalk) added for port 4500.
24.01.22  10:18:58  Forwarding to 192.168.178.69 (sfalk) added for port 500.
24.01.22  10:18:04  Event Log was deleted. This change was made in the home network from IP address 192.168.178.69 [sfalk].
```

#### `/var/log/ppp.log`

```
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : l2tp_get_router_address
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.178.1 from dict 1
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : L2TP connecting to server '85.237.31.244' (85.237.31.244)...
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : IPSec connection started
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : IPSec phase 1 client started
Thu Jan 20 09:47:07 2022 : IPSec phase 1 server replied
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : IPSec phase 2 started
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : IPSec phase 2 established
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : IPSec connection established
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP received SCCRP
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP sent SCCCN
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP sent ICRQ
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP received ICRP
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP sent ICCN
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP connection established.
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : L2TP set port-mapping for en0, interface: 6, protocol: 0, privatePort: 0
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : using link 0
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : Using interface ppp0
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:18]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x62b2ff57> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth eap> <magic 0xfb54e2f3>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFNAK.
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xfb54e2f3>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFACK.
Thu Jan 20 09:47:08 2022 : sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xfb54e2f3>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:09 2022 : L2TP failed to set port-mapping for en0, errorCode: -65564
Thu Jan 20 09:47:09 2022 : L2TP port-mapping for en0 became invalid. is Connected: 1, Protocol: None, Private Port: 0, Previous publicAddress: (0), Previous publicPort: (0)
Thu Jan 20 09:47:09 2022 : L2TP clearing port-mapping for en0
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x62b2ff57> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x62b2ff57> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x62b2ff57]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x82 <bbb842cfd05b65391f0820f7ec1c1b72>, name = "xl2tpd"]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [CHAP Response id=0x82 <a2927010ebf97d96742c7d737dfc48970000000000000000fc5ecb5fbcf32db7dae3b920fe97b4d44028989d613ddb3b00>, name = "sfalk"]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xfb54e2f3]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x82 "S=AF62F9AD454798E796FDA8AF4F151B7204E6C838"]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::f218:98ff:fe5f:11f2>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 10.255.255.0>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : ipcp: returning Configure-ACK
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 10.255.255.0>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 10.10.20.12> <ms-dns1 10.10.10.1> <ms-dns3 10.10.10.1>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 10.10.20.12> <ms-dns1 10.10.10.1> <ms-dns3 10.10.10.1>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 57 01 01 00 0e 01 0a f2 18 98 ff fe 5f 11 f2]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2 <addr 10.10.20.12> <ms-dns1 10.10.10.1> <ms-dns3 10.10.10.1>]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : ipcp: up
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : local  IP address 10.10.20.12
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : remote IP address 10.255.255.0
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : primary   DNS address 10.10.10.1
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : secondary DNS address 10.10.10.1
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : Received protocol dictionaries
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : l2tp_wait_input: Address added. previous interface setting (name: en0, address: 192.168.178.22), current interface setting (name: ppp0, family: PPP, address: 10.10.20.12, subnet: 255.0.0.0, destination: 10.255.255.0).
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : Committed PPP store on install command
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : rcvd [IPV6 data]
   60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   '`....$..........'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00   '................'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16   3a 00 05 02 00 00 01 00   '........:.......'
   8f 00 6e 8a 00 00 00 01   04 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00   '..n.............'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 02               '............'
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : Unsupported protocol 0x57 received
Thu Jan 20 09:47:11 2022 : sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x2 00 57 60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00 00 00 ...]
Thu Jan 20 09:47:12 2022 : rcvd [IPV6 data]
   60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   '`....$..........'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00   '................'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16   3a 00 05 02 00 00 01 00   '........:.......'
   8f 00 6e 8a 00 00 00 01   04 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00   '..n.............'
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 02               '............'
Thu Jan 20 09:47:12 2022 : Unsupported protocol 0x57 received
Thu Jan 20 09:47:12 2022 : sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 00 57 60 00 00 00 00 24 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 02 00 00 00 00 ...]
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP received StopCCN
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP hangup
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : ipcp: down
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : Connection terminated.
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP clearing port-mapping for en0
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : Connect time 1.6 minutes.
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : Sent 87703 bytes, received 50878 bytes.
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP disconnecting...
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP sent CDN
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP sent StopCCN
Thu Jan 20 09:48:39 2022 : L2TP disconnected
```

Comment: According to [osstatus.com](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-65564), this code maps to `kDNSServiceErr_NATPortMappingUnsupported`. The [documentation for this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/kdnsserviceerr_natportmappingunsupported) is: _"The NAT gateway doesn't support PCP, NAT-PMP or UPnP." _ So maybe macOS wants to set a mapping via UPnP on your gateway (router) but can't?

Comment: @DarkDust Hi, thanks for the hint. Didn't know osstatus.com until now. I've checked on my router and UPnP is enabled. All other devices here connect just fine so the issue might point to the VPN client?

Comment: @DarkDust fyi I also saw in the event log of my router that the ports 1701, 4500 and 500 are forwarded for my device.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine had the genius idea to re-create the VPN connection inside the Network settings.

He suggested this after I was able to connect over the router using my private PC without issues.

So the solution was to select the VPN config and a click on `[-]` followed by a click on `[+]`:

[image]

Words can't even describe how I feel about this but just in case you end up here: Delete the VPN connection and re-create it.

We still don't know:

- Why it did not work over my router
- Why it did work over the mobile hot spot